# Flex DataGrid Horizontal Scroll

Tags: apache-flex

I have a DataGrid that load data from a dataProvider in one column.
The problem is that the width of the column isn't too big to read all the info in the rows.
So I increase the column width... Now I need to scroll horizontaly, so I use `horizontalScrollPolicy="on"` in Datagrid options.

My problem: The horizontal scroll don't work.

```
<mx:DataGrid width="100%" id="gridDetail"
             dataProvider="{infoData}"
             styleName="dataGridStyle"
             headerStyleName="dgHeaderStyle"
             resizableColumns="false"
             sortableColumns="false" rowCount="4" horizontalScrollPolicy="on">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Information" dataField="@l" 
                           fontFamily="Lucida Console" letterSpacing="1"
                           textAlign="left" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: More information would be great. Does the Grid stretch to fill only the screen width, or does it expand past that? Does the scrollbar show? What's your code look like for the rest of the DataGrid declaration?

Comment: Please show your code and a screenshot of your issue.

Comment: The code you gave does not have `horizontalScrollPolicy="on"` which directly contradicts your question.

Comment: What happens if  you put the datagrid inside of a panel? Set the width to a numeric value (instead of 100%).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Turn on horizontalScrollPolicy .. e.g.

horizontalScrollPolicy="on"